# regular expression to automatically find which credit card type that is being entered. How do I code this in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, regex

I am trying to use regex to verify a credit card and automatically check the box type of the credit card without the user having to check it.

This is my code. JS file, html file. I am lost, can't get it to run. Any direction will be greatly appreciated:

index.htm

```
<body>
   <header>
      <h1>
         Hands-on Project 8-3
      </h1>
   </header>

   <article>
      <form action="results.htm">
         <fieldset id="paymentInfo" class="text">
            <legend>Payment Information</legend>
            <div class="offset">
               <label for="ccNum">Card #</label>
               <input id="ccNum" name="CardNumber" type="number" required="required" />
               <div id="ccNumErrorMessage"></div>
            </div>
            <div id="cards" class="inline">
               <input id="visa" name="PaymentType" type="radio" value="Visa" />
               <label for="visa">Visa</label>
               <input id="mc" name="PaymentType" type="radio" value="MC" />
               <label for="mc">Master Card</label>
               <input id="discover" name="PaymentType" type="radio" value="Discover" />
               <label for="discover">Discover</label>
               <input id="amex" name="PaymentType" type="radio" value="AmEx" />
               <label for="amex">American Express</label>
            </div>
            <div class="offset">
               <label>Expiration</label>
               <div class="inline" id="exp">
                  <label for="expMo" id="expMoLabel">Expiration Month</label>
                  <select id="expMo" name="ExpMonth" required="required">
                     <option value="01">01</option>
                     <option value="02">02</option>
                     <option value="03">03</option>
                     <option value="04">04</option>
                     <option value="05">05</option>
                     <option value="06">06</option>
                     <option value="07">07</option>
                     <option value="08">08</option>
                     <option value="09">09</option>
                     <option value="10">10</option>
                     <option value="11">11</option>
                     <option value="12">12</option>
                  </select>
                  <label for="expYr" id="expYrLabel">Expiration Year</label>
                  <select id="expYr" name="ExpYear" required="required">
                     <option value="2017">2017</option>
                     <option value="2018">2018</option>
                     <option value="2019">2019</option>
                     <option value="2020">2020</option>
                     <option value="2021">2021</option>
                  </select>
               </div>
               <label for="cvv">CVV</label>
               <input id="cvv" name="CVVValue" type="number" required="required" /> 
            </div>
         </fieldset>
      </form>
   </article>

<script src="script1.js"></script>   
</body>
</html>
```

script1.js

```
/*    JavaScript 
 *    Filename: script1.js
 */

"use strict";

function selectCardType() {
  // local variables
  var cardNumValue = document.getElementById("ccNum").value,
    var visa = /^4[0-9]{12}(?:[0-9]{3})?$/,
      var mc = /^5[1-5][0-9]{14}$/,
        var discover = /^6(?:011|5[0-9]{2})[0-9{12}$/],
  var amex = /^3[47][0-9]{13}$/,

    if (visa.test(cardNumValue)) {
      document.getElementById("visa").checked = "checked";
    } else
  if (mc.test(cardNumValue)) {
    document.getElementById("mc").checked = "checked";

  } else if (discover.test(cardNumValue)) {
    document.getElementById("discover").checked = "checked";
  } else if (amex.test(cardNumValue)) {

    document.getElementById("amex").checked = "checked";
  }

}

function createEventListeners() {
  var cardNum = document.getElementById("ccNum");
  if (cardNum.addEventListener) {
    cardNum.addEventListener("change", selectCardType, false);
  } else if (cardNum.attachEvent) {
    cardNum.attachEvent("onchange", selectCardType);
  }
}
if (window.addEventListener) {

  window.addEventListener("load", createEventListeners, false);

} else if (window.attachEvent) {
  window.attachEvent("onload", createEventListeners);
}

}
```

Comment: There is a standard numbering format to determine which brand it is. Google it !

Comment: @sln He already has that in his regexps.

Comment: You have an extra `}` at the end of the Javascript.

Comment: Are there any errors in the Javascript console?

Comment: What error is it throwing?

Comment: I've downvoted because I noticed a syntax error, which means you obviously posted before checking the console for errors.

Comment: I am not gettting any errors.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [Luhn algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luhn_algorithm) to determine if the number is a credit card number. For determining the brand, you can simply tell by looking at the cards first digit.

First digit of card types:

- Visa: 4
- MasterCard: 5
- Discover: 6
- Amex: 3

Here is an example of a `luhn algrithm` in JavaScript:

```
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// FUNCTION - VALIDATE CREDIT CARD NUMBER (original code by DiegoSalazar)
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
function validateCardNumber(value){

    // ACCEPT ONLY DIGITS, DASHES OR SPACES
    if(/[^0-9-\s]+/.test(value)){

        return false;

    }

    // LUHN ALGORITHM
    var nCheck = 0;
    var nDigit = 0;
    var bEven = false;

    // REMOVE SPACES
    value = value.replace(/\D/g,"");

    // LOOP
    for(var n = value.length - 1; n >= 0; n--){

        // SET VALUES
        var cDigit = value.charAt(n);
        var nDigit = parseInt(cDigit, 10);

        // CHECK FOR EVEN
        if(bEven){

            // CHECK FOR SOMETHING
            if((nDigit *= 2) > 9){

                // SUBSRACT 9
                nDigit -= 9;

            }

        }

        // INCREASE
        nCheck += nDigit;
        bEven = !bEven;

    }

    // RETURN
    return (nCheck % 10) == 0;

} // END FUNCTION
```

Comment: The function `selectCardType()` determines the brand.

Comment: What does Luhn checking have to do with the problem he's having getting the Javascript functions to run?

Comment: @Barmar a Luhn check is the most accurate way to verify a credit card without sending it to a processor.

Comment: I know that. But that's not what he asked in the question. He's trying to set the credit card type automatically, with his function `selectCardType()`.

Answer (score -2):

You have a syntax error in your code:

```
// local variables
var cardNumValue = document.getElementById("ccNum").value,
    var visa = /^4[0-9]{12}(?:[0-9]{3})?$/,
    var mc = /^5[1-5][0-9]{14}$/,
    var discover = /^6(?:011|5[0-9]{2})[0-9{12}$/],
    var amex = /^3[47][0-9]{13}$/,
```

You should not repeat the `var` keyword before each variable, and you should end the declaration statement with `;`, not `,`. Also, the `discover` regexp has the last `]` in the wrong place -- it should be after `0-9`, but it's after `/`. (BTW, `[0-9]` can be replaced with `\d`).

So it should be:

```
// local variables
var cardNumValue = document.getElementById("ccNum").value,
    visa = /^4[0-9]{12}(?:[0-9]{3})?$/,
    mc = /^5[1-5][0-9]{14}$/,
    discover = /^6(?:011|5[0-9]{2})[0-9]{12}$/,
    amex = /^3[47][0-9]{13}$/;
```

Or you could make each declaration a separate statement, so they each need to end with `;`, not `,`

```
// local variables
var cardNumValue = document.getElementById("ccNum").value;
var visa = /^4[0-9]{12}(?:[0-9]{3})?$/;
var mc = /^5[1-5][0-9]{14}$/;
var discover = /^6(?:011|5[0-9]{2})[0-9]{12}$/;
var amex = /^3[47][0-9]{13}$/;
```

You also have an unmatched `}` at the end of `script1.js`.

Comment: Ah the old multiple declaration.